# ARM car Head Unit - extract rootfs from cpio

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, firmware, cpio

Got an ARM powered head unit and im trying to get the rootfs (ramdisk) out of the kernel image.
I found uImage header and was able to extract the zImage. Using binwalk i found gzip data in the zImage, which I also extracted. I get a file called 20C50.cpio, which im unable to extract. Just getting an empty dev/root folder. Seems to be jffs2 filesystem. Can anyone point me, to how I can extract the whole thing?
Heres the File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/45f0f8pg9ec1sa4/kernelImage?dl=0

Best regards

```
root@fhem:/tmp# binwalk zImage

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
18536         0x4868          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)


root@fhem:/tmp# gunzip zImage
gzip: zImage: unknown suffix -- ignored

root@fhem:/tmp# binwalk -Me zImage

Scan Time:     2018-06-09 14:34:51
Target File:   /tmp/zImage
MD5 Checksum:  edb358efbc5f4252ca9ff8ba0c3ac091
Signatures:    344

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
18536         0x4868          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)


Scan Time:     2018-06-09 14:34:56
Target File:   /tmp/_zImage-0.extracted/4868
MD5 Checksum:  c5d093ad29222c46d171a3884d3793e9
Signatures:    344

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
134224        0x20C50         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev", file name length: "0x00000004", file s                              ize: "0x00000000"
134340        0x20CC4         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev/console", file name length: "0x0000000C"                              , file size: "0x00000000"
134464        0x20D40         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "root", file name length: "0x00000005", file                               size: "0x00000000"
134580        0x20DB4         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B",                               file size: "0x00000000"
1833149       0x1BF8BD        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1284
1833269       0x1BF935        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1288
1834033       0x1BFC31        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1284
3349809       0x331D31        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1284
3349845       0x331D55        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1284
3800509       0x39FDBD        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1292
3800513       0x39FDC1        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1316
3800517       0x39FDC5        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1320
4123848       0x3EECC8        Linux kernel version "3.0.35-5.1.6-g6498a9a (changchun@HP-640) (gcc version 4.6.2 20110630 (pre                              release) (Freescale MAD -- Linaro 2011.07 -- Built at 2"
4137860       0x3F2384        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
4212648       0x4047A8        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
5111543       0x4DFEF7        Unix path: /S70/S75/505V/F505/F707/F717/P8
5138231       0x4E6737        Unix path: /media/common/tuners/tda18271-maps.c
5142311       0x4E7727        Unix path: /media/common/tuners/tda18271-common.c
5174182       0x4EF3A6        Copyright string: "Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman"
5187999       0x4F299F        Unix path: /mxc/gpu-viv/hal/os/linux/kernel/gc_hal_kernel_os.c
5194000       0x4F4110        Unix path: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu
5247196       0x5010DC        Neighborly text, "NeighborSolicits6InDatagrams"
5247216       0x5010F0        Neighborly text, "NeighborAdvertisementsorts"


Scan Time:     2018-06-09 14:35:12
Target File:   /tmp/_zImage-0.extracted/_4868.extracted/3F2384
MD5 Checksum:  9d5e50053f708a31f0fc42e3cb19c72f
Signatures:    344

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16830         0x41BE          MPFS filesystem, Microchop, version 32.105, 8307 file entries
49593         0xC1B9          MPFS filesystem, Microchop, version 61.121, 8970 file entries
49610         0xC1CA          MPFS filesystem, Microchop, version 95.80, 21327 file entries
49646         0xC1EE          MPFS filesystem, Microchop, version 95.88, 21569 file entries
```

Comment: binwalk often give misleading information.  I managed to extract the `config` from the image.  There is a cpio as well, but the config has *CONFIG_CMDLINE="noinitrd console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw rootfstype=jffs2 ip=off"* as well as *CONFIG_CMDLINE_FROM_BOOTLOADER=y*, so uBoot may be saying don't do any initrd type stuff.  The ramfs looks like a very minimal file system with nothing in it, but I am not sure that I extracted it properly.

Comment: Your first step is to strip the uboot header with `dd if=kernelImage of=test skip=64 bs=1`... then you have a zImage binary.  It has multiple things attached to it, not just a cpio.

Comment: Hi, yes i also found this config. In the zImage I found a kernel config file (the gzip data right after Linux kernel ). I wonder if these DER certificates are false positives.  What’s  with the data between last cpio and first DER certificate? I was not able to extract any further useable stuff.